# Emitting a signal from the same slot it is connected to

Tags: c++, qt

Can i emit the signal which slot is connected from the same slot again. I will make the emit from slot conditional and happen only once,to avoid recursive calling.Can this lead to an issue?

I'm working with a Qt application involving signals and slots. A signal is emitted from a state machine running in a separate thread, initiated by a function in Class A. After the state machine completes, it emits a signal connected to a slot in Class B. In the slot execution, I'm calling the same function to run the state machine again. Could this approach potentially cause issues?

Comment: Have you tried it?  When Qt sees a signal, it doesn't know from where it came from.  If you want to cause infinite recursion, that's entirely up to you.

Comment: As i mentioned, the state machine which emits the signal will be called only once from the slot, as it is conditional. So this will not cause recursion.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware it is forbidden to emit a signal recursively, but it may not be the best solution.

Even if you avoid infinite recursion and use a separate thread it may have the undesired side effects of slots being called out of order if multiple slots are connected to the same signal. F.ex. assume signal A is (directly) connected consecutively to slot B and slot C. Slot B (sometimes) emits signal A again. The order of execution will be:

- B(1)
- B(2)
- A(2)
- A(1)

Using queued connections may avoid this issue. Depending on your specific situation, it may be possible/better to avoid the recursion at all.

Reading about the [Qt State Machine Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html) may be useful too.